# console.log and progress event - only shows when 100%

Tags: javascript, console, progress-bar, progress

I'm testing a progress bar.

So I do something like :

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
    var percent;

    if (event.lengthComputable === true) {
        percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        console.log(percent);
    } 
});
```

I expected to see multiple growing percentages in the console, like I see in the related tutorials.

Instead, only 100 is logged, both with firebug and chrome developper.

What's wrong ?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: link to related tutorials?

Comment: Maybe your AJAX request finished it all in one request. Does it log 100% multiple times or just once?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be-GSVO7PGQ , see at 9:39

Comment: hmm.. is your XHR object sync or async?..

Comment: It log 100% only once.

Comment: the xhr 3rd parameter is not specified, so it use default (true, = async)  ; nothing is logged when using false

Comment: `If the length of the HTTP entity body is known through the Content-Length header, initialize the lengthComputable attribute to true and initialize the total attribute to the length` https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html .. is your server response (stream) specifying the size of the response content?

Comment: oh.. it's for uploads.. there is a different progressevent for that.. `xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress')`

Comment: @trogne, try to add an **else** statement after your `if (event.lengthComputable)` to see if it logs anything. If so, that means the total length is not known, and it will be zero. Just curious if **lengthComputable** is ever false in the progression.

Comment: @Brett Caswell, thanks! .upload. was missing!

Answer (score 1):

upload was missing there : `xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress')`
Thanks to Brett Caswell.